# How do I use DenseNet121 in MONAI?

Tags: pixel, metrics, medical-imaging, densenet

I have CT images (512x512x84) and the labels are those CT images but segmented after I used ITK_snap to "Paint" an specific tissue (Ocular tissue) , the image files are stored in train_images and the labels in Train_Labels, then I create a dictionary to which i create a dataset and apply the MONAI transforms.

The issue is when I try to use densenet 121 or any other model, after the transforms I get that the tensor size is [1,1,512,512,1], when I introduce this datasets into the model i get the error that input image size        (T:128,H:128,W:1) can't be smaller than kernel size (KT:2,KH:2,KW:2), so I tried UNet which it kind of works because I have to use squeeze due to UNet changes the value in the last position of the tensor from [1,1,512,512,1] to [1,1,512,512,2] and I get error but using squeeze I turn the 2 into a 1. I'm using confusion matrix as a metric in the `model.eval()` section. I created a list where I store the values from the matrix after each EPOCH and I get this:

```
TN metatensor(1073321133, device='cuda:0')
FP metatensor(24578667, device='cuda:0')
FN metatensor(3014885, device='cuda:0')
TP metatensor(90115, device='cuda:0')
metatensor(1101004800, device='cuda:0')(FP+FN+TP+TN)
```

which is weird because for what I understand it should be 512x512x84 = 22020096 pixel value.

The MONAI version is 1.3.0 and I'm using Visual Studio Code.

```py
import logging
import os
import monai
import sys
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import torch

from torch import squeeze

from torchmetrics.classification import Recall
from torchmetrics.classification import Accuracy
from torchmetrics.classification import BinaryRecall
from torchmetrics.classification import BinaryPrecision
from torchmetrics.classification import BinaryAUROC
from torchmetrics.classification import BinarySpecificity
from torchmetrics.classification import Dice
from torchmetrics.classification import BinaryConfusionMatrix

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from monai.utils import first
#from torchmetrics.classification import BinaryF1Score
from torchmetrics.functional.classification import binary_f1_score
from monai.data import decollate_batch, DataLoader,Dataset

from monai.metrics import ROCAUCMetric
from torchmetrics.classification import BinaryF1Score
from monai.transforms import SqueezeDimd, Activations,ToTensord, AsDiscrete, Compose, LoadImaged, RandRotate90d, Resized, ScaleIntensityd,EnsureChannelFirstd,RandFlipd,RandZoomd,RandGaussianNoised,SqueezeDimd

from monai.networks.nets import DenseNet121,UNet,RegUNet,VNet
from monai.networks.blocks import UnetResBlock,ResBlock


def main():
    monai.config.print_config()
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)
    data_dir="C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/POSGRADO VIU/Prácticas/Datasets/archive/files/aneurismamonai"

    train_images = sorted(glob(os.path.join(data_dir,"TrainData","*.dcm")))
    train_labels = sorted(glob(os.path.join(data_dir,"TrainLabel","*.dcm")))

    val_images = sorted(glob(os.path.join(data_dir,"ValData","*.dcm")))

    val_labels = sorted(glob(os.path.join(data_dir,"ValLabel","*.dcm")))

    train_files=[{"image":image,"label":label} for image,label in zip(train_images,train_labels)]
    val_files=[{"image":image,"label":label} for image,label in zip(val_images,val_labels)]
  
    print (len(train_files))
   


  
    train_transforms = Compose(
    [
        LoadImaged(keys=["image","label"]),
        EnsureChannelFirstd(keys=["image","label"]),
        ScaleIntensityd(keys=["image"]),
        RandRotate90d(keys=["image"], prob=0.5, spatial_axes=[0, 1]),
        
        
        #RandZoomd(keys=["image","label"],min_zoom=0.9, max_zoom=1.1, prob=0.5, keep_size=True),
        #Resized(keys=["image","label"], spatial_size=(512, 512)),
  
        
        
       
        
    ]
    )
    val_transforms = Compose(
        [
            LoadImaged(keys=["image","label"]),
            EnsureChannelFirstd(keys=["image","label"]),
            ScaleIntensityd(keys=["image","label"]),

            #Resized(keys=["image","label"], spatial_size=(512, 512, 2)),
            
            #ToTensord(keys=["image","label"]),
        ]
    )
    


    train_ds=Dataset(data=train_files,transform=train_transforms)
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_ds,batch_size=1,num_workers=1,pin_memory=torch.cuda.is_available())#batch se refiere a la canitad de imagenes a usar en las iteraciones 
    first_batch = next(iter(train_loader))
    print (len(train_loader))
    dataset_size = len(train_loader.dataset)  # Number of samples in the dataset
    batch_size = train_loader.batch_size  # Size of each batch

    print(f"Dataset size: {dataset_size}")
    print(f"Batch size: {batch_size}")
    
    
    
    primer_dato = first_batch["image"]
    primer_dato=primer_dato.squeeze(-1)
    print("XD",primer_dato.shape)
    

    #
    
    
    val_ds=Dataset(data=val_files,transform=val_transforms)
    val_loader =DataLoader(val_ds,batch_size=1)
    
    

    
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    #model = DenseNet121(spatial_dims=3, in_channels=1, out_channels=1,pretrained=False).to(device)#in channels es detemrinado si la imagen es de escala de grises o de color, al ser una imagen
    #model = ResBlock(spatial_dims=3, in_channels=1,norm="BATCH",kernel_size=1, act=('RELU', {'inplace': True})).to(device)
    model = UNet(spatial_dims=3,in_channels=1,out_channels=1,channels=(16,32),strides=(2,2,2)).to(device)
    

    loss_function = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    #loss_function = torch.nn.L1Loss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), 1e-5)
    #auc_metric = ROCAUCMetric()
   

   
    val_interval = 2
    best_metric = -1
    best_metric_epoch = -1
    epoch_loss_values = []
    metric_values = []
    c00=[]
    c01=[]
    c10=[]
    c11=[]
    
    numepoch=100
    

    for epoch in range(numepoch):
        print("-" * 10)
        print(f"epoch {epoch + 1}/{numepoch}")
        model.train()
        epoch_loss = 0
        step = 0
        for batch_data in train_loader:
            step += 1
            inputs,labels = (batch_data["image"].to(device),batch_data["label"].to(device))
          
            
            print("inputs",inputs.shape)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(inputs)#BUSCAR LOS PIXELES, convertir a pixeles 
            outputs = outputs[:,:,:,:,1]# unet, sirve
            outputs = outputs.unsqueeze(4)#unet,sirve
            print("outputs",outputs.shape)          
        
            loss = loss_function(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            labels=labels.long()
            accuracy=Accuracy(task="Binary").to(device)#que tan cercanos son los valores a una medida 
            #f1=BinaryF1Score().to(device)
            metricac=accuracy(outputs,labels)
            speci=BinarySpecificity().to(device)#que resultados no son negativos 
            metric4=speci(outputs,labels)
           
            print("Accuracy:",metricac)#epoch 1 = 0.7937 epoch3=0.7938#accuracy metric 
            
            print("Sensitivity",metric4)
            
           
            
            #se puede calcular las matricas , precisionmetric pytorch , auc area bajo la curva roc
            #evaluacion atraves de la perdida
            epoch_len = len(train_ds) // train_loader.batch_size
            print(f"{step}/{epoch_len}, train_loss: {loss.item():.4f}")
           # writer.add_scalar("train_loss", loss.item(), epoch_len * epoch + step)
        epoch_loss /= step
        epoch_loss_values.append(epoch_loss)
       
        print(f"epoch {epoch + 1} average loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}")
        
        if (epoch + 1) % val_interval == 0:
            model.eval()
            num_correct = 0.0
            metric_count = 0
            with torch.no_grad():
                
                for val_data in val_loader:
                    val_images, val_labels = val_data["image"].to(device), val_data["label"].to(device)
                    
                    val_outputs = model(val_images)
                    val_outputs = val_outputs[:,:,:,:,1]
                    val_outputs = val_outputs.unsqueeze(4)
                    #outputsval=val_outputs.data.resize_(1,1,128,128,84)
                    value = torch.eq(val_outputs.argmax(dim=1), val_labels.argmax(dim=1))
                    metric_count += len(value)
                    num_correct += value.sum().item()
                    bcm = BinaryConfusionMatrix().to(device)
                    len2=len(val_data)
                    val_labels2=(val_labels>=0.5).float()
                    metric1eval=bcm(val_outputs,val_labels2)
                    print("Matriz",metric1eval)
                    c1=metric1eval[0][0]
                    c2=metric1eval[0][1]
                    c3=metric1eval[1][0]
                    c4=metric1eval[1][1]
                    c00.append(c1)
                    c01.append(c2)
                    c10.append(c3)
                    c11.append(c4)
                    print("longitud",len2)
                    print(c1,c2)
                    print(c1+c2)
                    recall=BinaryRecall().to(device)
                    metricac=accuracy(outputs,labels)
                    print("Accuracy:",metricac)
                    metric2=recall(outputs,labels)#de los verdaderos postivos, cuantos son prececidos como positivos 
                    precision=BinaryPrecision().to(device)
                    metric3=precision(outputs,labels)
                    dice=Dice().to(device)#Similitud entre dos conjuntos de datos 
                    metric5=dice(outputs,labels)
                    print("Recall:",metric2)
                    print("Precision",metric3)
                    print("Dice",metric5)

                    #calculo de metricas la imagen puedo o no tener ojos, matriz de confusion 
                metric = num_correct / metric_count
                metric_values.append(metric)

                if metric > best_metric:
                    best_metric = metric
                    best_metric_epoch = epoch + 1
                    torch.save(model.state_dict(), "best_metric_model_classification3d_array.pth")
                    print("saved new best metric model")

                print(f"Current epoch: {epoch+1} current accuracy: {metric:.4f} ")
                print(f"Best accuracy: {best_metric:.4f} at epoch {best_metric_epoch}")
            #writer.add_scalar("val_accuracy", metric, epoch + 1)
        
  
    #print("Matriz",metric1eval)
    totalsum00= sum([num for num in c00])
    totalsum01= sum([num2 for num2 in c01])
    totalsum10= sum([num3 for num3 in c10])
    totalsum11= sum([num4 for num4 in c11])
    print("TN",totalsum00)
    print("FP",totalsum01)
    print("FN",totalsum10)
    print("TP",totalsum11)
    #total1=sum(totalsum00,totalsum01)
    #total2=sum(totalsum10,totalsum11)
    result=torch.add(totalsum11,totalsum00)
    result2=torch.add(totalsum01,totalsum10)
    res=torch.add(result,result2)
    print(res)
   
    
    
   
     
    print(f"Training completed, best_metric: {best_metric:.4f} at epoch: {best_metric_epoch}")
    valx=[i + 1 for i in range (len(epoch_loss_values))]
    valy= epoch_loss_values
    plt.xlabel("Epoch")
    plt.plot(valx,valy)
    plt.show()
 
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```